# Update/Replace with line breaks not executing

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having issues with an update/replace.

Here's the field data I'm trying to work on:

```
--- 
- "true"
- "false"
- "true"
```

Here's the query:

```
UPDATE table SET field = replace (field, '--- \r\n- ', '')
```

It needs to end up as:

```
"true"
- "false"
- "true"
```

I add some WHERE criteria, but it keeps saying 0 rows affected. What could I be missing?

Comment: are you sure its `\r\n` it could be just `\n`

Comment: Yup. That was it. :P Thanx

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
create table yourtable (field varchar(100));

insert into yourtable values ('--- 
- "true"
- "false"
- "true"');

update yourtable 
set field = replace(field, '--- \n- ', '');
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2959f/1